# how to mock nested interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, unit-of-work

i'm trying to mock a IUnitOfWork interface

```
Mock<IUnitOfWork> mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
```

the IUnitOfWork interface holds other interfaces.
so i want to mock a function inside Customer interface inside IUintOfWork

```
mock.Setup(s => s.Customer.GetActiveCustomerByIdCard("lala"))
            .Returns(new Customer());
```

i pass the mock.Object to class under test

```
var manager = new CustomerManager(mock.Object);
        var res = manager.AddNewCustomer(new Customer());
```

my problem is when the mock function return null

```
var customer = _unitOfWork.Customer.GetActiveCustomerByIdCard(idCard);
```

when i debug the test i see the mock in CustomerManager class but the function return null

Comment: Are you passing the same id used during setup? If not the mock will return null

Comment: @juharr Moq allows for nested mocks. What the OP has is valid. Most likely the setup uses a different id to what is used when invoked.

Comment: @Nkosi Which id are you mining ?

Comment: the `"lala"`. Is that the exact same as what is passed when exercising the test?

Comment: use `It.IsAny<string>()` to ignore the parameter value

Comment: @Nkosi Yep you right!!!! i changed it, its work! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the setup uses a different value to what is used when the mock is invoked.

Use `It.IsAny<string>()` to ignore the parameter value

```
mock
    .Setup(s => s.Customer.GetActiveCustomerByIdCard(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(new Customer());
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart : Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)